# Insert rows into multiple tables in SQL Server 2008 from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net, transactions

I have a problem regarding data insertion in multiple tables from my asp.net application.

I just want to insert rows into three tables but if due to any reason insertion fails then it must be deleted from all 3 tables i.e. I want it atomic as either records are inserted in all three tables or not in any.

I tried to implement using transaction but it's not working well as other rows are not being read at the time of insertion.

I am not getting where I am wrong or what else should I do to achieve this.

Looking forward for kind solutions of yours.

Thanks in adv
Supriya

Comment: Transactions are guaranteed to be atomic so it is likely you've got a bug of some sort. Please could you post a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: can you post your problem , what query you have written in  this regard

Comment: Please show us your code, it's hard to answer theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

> THIS CODE IS FOR SAVING SINGLE ENTRY IN ONE TABLE AND DETAILS FROM GRID SAVING TO DETAIL TABLE

```
public int FN_InserMultpleinsecondtable(ENT_firsttablevalue entDCn,List<ENT_scndtablevalue> LstEnt)
    {
        long DataResult = 0; long HistResult = 0;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(classname.ConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            SqlTransaction trans;
            trans = cn.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("[StoredProcedurefor1st-table]", cn, trans);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = entDCn.colMas_id_DM;

            DataResult = Convert.ToInt64(1);

            if (DataResult > 0)
            {
                foreach (ENT_scndtablevalue entLoc in LstEnt)
                {

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("storedprocedurefor2nd table multiple insert", cn, trans);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = entLoc.Name;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MobNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = entLoc.Mobno;
                                                HistResult = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar());


                }
            }


            if (HistResult > 0)
            {
                trans.Commit();
                return Convert.ToInt32(DataResult);
            }
            else
            {
                trans.Rollback();
                return -1;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
            trans.Rollback();
            trans.Dispose();
            return 0;
        }
    }


}
```

> in Class Name ENT_firsttablevalue  and ENT_scndtablevalue declare variables like this

public int Name
{ get; set; }

> Like This 
>   and In Button save code is
>
> this code is inside the button save command

```
ENT_firsttablevalue EntDObj = new ENT_firsttablevalue ();
EntDObj.colMas_id_DM = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
List<ENT_scndtablevalue> LstDEnt = new List<ENT_scndtablevalue>();
{
  for (int i = 0; i < GridView.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    LstDEnt.Add(new ENT_scndtablevalue
    {
      Name= (GridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text).ToString(),
      Mob= (GridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text).ToString(),
    });
  }
  long resu = dalDobj.FN_InserMultpleinsecondtable(EntDObj, LstDEnt);
```